# Кодировка в MySql - поддержка украинского со знаком ударения

Tags: mysql, кодировка, unicode

Для MySql-таблицы нужна кодировка, которая поддерживает украинский язык и нечувствительная к регистру.
До сих пор использовал кодировку `utf8_unicode_ci`. Но появилась проблема: буквы "і" и "ї" распознаются одинаково. Поэтому, например, слова "іжак" и "їжак" неразличимы и, при поиске одного из слов, второе выдается также.

Пробовал использовать кодировку `utf8_unicode_520_ci`, но тогда одинаковыми для сравнения становятся "г" и "ґ".

Пробовал изменить кодировку на [предложенные Oracle-ом для кириллицы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html), но они не поддерживают знак ударения (" ́ ").

Вариант с `binary` не подходит, поскольку необходима нечувствительность к регистру.

Буду признателен к любым идеям, что помогут в решении.

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать utf8_bin и искать с `lower()` обеих строк. Конечно скорей всего придётся поплатится другими полезными преобразованиями символов. Если скорость критична, то можно создать `GENERATED`-поле с индексом. Адекватного способа [создать](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-collation-unicode-uca.html) свой collate со всякими вкусностями я не нашёл.